# How can I obtain the circumference coordinates of a tilted circle in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

The perimeter coordinates of the non-tilted circles, like the image above, were obtained with the following code.

```
//c=Center
//r=radius
//i=angle
Vector3 FindPoint(Vector3 c, float r, int i)
{
    return c + Quaternion.AngleAxis(1.0f * i, Vector3.forward) * (Vector3.right * r);
}

//Example of securing coordinates
for(int i=0;i<360;i++)
{
    point[i] = FindPoint(center, radius, i);
}
```

[image]

But, as in the image above, I need to get the circumference coordinates for the circles that are tilted in the x-axis.

How do you know the three-dimensional coordinates of the circumference of a tilted circle when you know the origin and radius and the tilted values ​​along the x-axis?

Answer (score 2):

From unity documentation: 
**Unlike Vector3.forward, Transform.forward moves the GameObject while also considering its rotation.**
So, you can replace this line:

```
return c + Quaternion.AngleAxis(1.0f * i, Vector3.forward) * (Vector3.right * r);
```

with the following one:

```
return c + Quaternion.AngleAxis(1.0f * i, transform.forward) * (transform.right * r);
```

**I guessed your script is attached to the tilted object so used transform. Otherwise, you need to use it like tiltedObj.transform.